# How to use mono_add_internal_call properly if C++ project and C# dll are under different directory

Tags: c#, c++, unity-game-engine, mono

I have a C++ project which want to invoke function in C# dll, therefore I followed the mono-document, and have below code in C++ project:

```
static MonoString* Sample()
{
    return mono_string_new(mono_domain_get(), "Hello CPP");
}

int main()
{
    domain = mono_jit_init("MyGame");

    MonoAssembly* assembly = mono_domain_assembly_open(domain, unity_main_dll_path);
    image = mono_assembly_get_image(assembly);

    mono_add_internal_call("Game.Call2Cpp::TestCall", Sample);

    return 0;
}
```

Then, I have this code in C# which actually is an unity project:

```
namespace Game
{
    public class Call2Cpp : MonoBehaviour
    {
        [MethodImplAttribute(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall)]
        static extern void TestCall();

        void Update()
        {
            if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.T))
            {
                TestCall();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And when I test it, I press "T" in unity runtime, it occured an error:

```
MissingMethodException:  assembly:<unknown assembly> type:<unknown type> member:(null)
Game.Call2Cpp.Update () (at Assets/Scripts/Game/Multiplayer/Call2Cpp.cs:26)
```

I'm wondering that the reason maybe the C++ project and Unity Project are under different directory:

C++ project path is /Project/Server/Main.cpp, and Unity Project is under /Project/Client, and there are some reason that I can't move them under a same directory. But anyway, I'm not sure this is the actual reason or not.

So my question are:

1. Is the different path caused this problem occurred, how can I use "mono_add_internal_call" properly under this situation?
2. Is there any alternate way to call C# code from C++ through mono under this situation?
3. I've wondering is that my usage of this mono api is incorrect at the very beginning, but after quite a searching work on google, found out the others call the mono_add_internal_call just like what i did , then the work is done, it seems there are no more extra code before and after that.
4. Then I have remove the Monobehavior on Call2Cpp.cs, because I can't found the class when I was trying call C# from C++, and I call the Call2Cpp.TestCall() from another script, but same error occurred.

Comment: there is plenty of info out there, and you need to build it with the right .net, you put it in the right folder, despite having never done it, a while ago there was a question, i tried what the guy did, corrected the version and it worked.. so it is very simple.

Comment: instead of the `MethodImplAttribute` shouldn't it rather be `[DllImport ("PluginName")]`? see e.g. [Native Plugins](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/NativePlugins.html) or [Low-level native plug-in interface](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/NativePluginInterface.html) ... afaik Unity only uses `MethodImplAttribute` for **their** hooks into the native Unity Core (since basically the entire c# API is just a more user friendly layer on top of the engine)